# How can we migrate the data directly from source to target table in ODI

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

How can we remove the stagging table in ODI, want to migrate the data directly from source to target table in ODI.
Inserting the data from source to staging and then to target causing performance issue for migrating huge table having millions records.
Is there way we can map the tables and move the data from source table(sql server table) to target table (oracle table) skipping the staging table.

Comment: Look for available KMs or write your own

Comment: we got the way to do it in ODI 11g but want to do it in ODI 12c.   http://s3.amazonaws.com/Ora/ODI-Simple_SELECT_and_INSERT-interface.swf

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you want, but disabling the control flow does that, among other things:

[image]